# Ignore errors in environments in latex-suite in vim

Tags: listings, vim, vim-latex

I use the `latex-suite` vim plugin, which shows me errors inline in my vim editor. However, I get false positives for certain environments like `lstlistings`. How can I configure `latex-suite` to ignore these environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would go about doing this is to make the `lstlisting` environment (and any other environments which also have this problem) have the same syntax highlighting as the `verbatim` environment: a single colored block, with special TeX symbols like `$` and `%` treated like ordinary text.

This means that you can accomplish this without worrying about `latex-suite` at all: [`latex-suite` doesn't change your syntax highlighting.](http://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/message/29492276/) The first step is to make sure your `.tex` files are syntax highlighted, which you may have done already. If not, put the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
filetype on
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex,*.sty,*.cls set filetype=tex
au FileType tex syntax on
```

It turns out that for vim's LaTeX syntax highlighter, a `verbatim` environment defines a `texZone` region, so all we need to do is ensure that the `lstlisting` environment also defines a `texZone` region:

```
au filetype tex syntax region texZone start='\\begin{lstlisting}' end='\\end{lstlisting}'
```

This incantation means "whenever we're working with a TeX file, append to the `texZone` definition the *region* between `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}`."

Then, reload your file, and `verbatim` and `lstlisting` environments will look the same.

[image]

And of course you can replace `lstlisting` with other environments that have this problem.

### Caveats

- If you use a non-default syntax highlighting language definition for TeX, this may not work. (Different colorschemes are okay.) In that case, though, you can still determine what syntax item the `verbatim` environment represents by typing `:echom synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."),1),"name")` while in command mode in a `verbatim` environment, and then use the returned syntax group instead of `texZone`.
- This solution does not handle the optional environment argument to `lstlistings`; since this is LaTeX code rather than part of the listing, it would be nice for the syntax highlighting to reflect that. I do not know how to do that, and it might become a difficult parsing/regex problem (since it could contain nested brackets).
- Apparently, the vim consensus is that `latex-suite` is [not a good plugin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48259); this link recommends a few alternatives.

Comment: Can this also apply to `\lstlisting{}`?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian Can `\lstlisting` be used as a command instead of an environment? I've never heard of that, couldn't get it to work just now when I tried it, and couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `\lstinline{}`.

Comment: I think you can, but it would be a regex that I don't know how to make: like `\verb`, `\lstinline` can accept many different characters as delimiters (e.g. `\lstinline_foo_` or `\lstinline+foo+`), and I don't know how to make a vim regex with arbitrary delimiters.